# Is there a way to test if an html element can accept an attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so i could make an array of elements and test against it but that wouldn't be very practical.

I was wondering if there's a way to do something like:

if (el accepts attrName) do something.

EDIT: I'm referring to this list https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: Every html element can accept an attribute

Comment: What you mean by `el accepts attrName` ? Checking for existence ?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran for example certain elements can have have attribute as <li value="1"> while others don't.

Comment: no you can add any attribute to any html tag, it's browser who will skip the attribute behavior if that attribute is unknown to browser

Comment: @localZero What elements don't accept an attribute `value`?

Comment: @MarcCompte — Most of them. HTML 5 only defines 10 elements which *do* accept a value attribute.

Comment: @Quentin OP said nothing about HTML5 in his question nor in his answers, nor did he mention "accept" should mean being compliant with HTML3 , HTML5 or any other specification. `<div>` does technically `accept` an attribute `value` even though it is not HTML5 compliant and you can fetch it with Javascript too (at least in chrome).

Comment: @MarcCompte — That depends on your definition of accept.

Comment: @MarcCompte yeah you're right, should have been a bit more accurate. I am referencing to this list https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: @Quentin not really, depends on the OPs definition of `accept`. If he means HTML5 compliant, then you are right and AFAIK there is no way of telling unless you build a list of compliant attributes in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers provide no API to tell you what attributes are recognised.

If you were to limit your requirements to HTML 3.2, HTML 4 or XHTML 1, then you could parse a DTD to get your list of supported attributes for each element. e.g. [the HTML 4.01 Strict DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html). This would require that you find or write a JavaScript DTD parser.

HTML 5 doesn't provide an official machine readable spec. You could try parsing [the table of data](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/fullindex.html#attributes-table) in the index (the format of which I note has changed between HTML 5 and HTML 5.1)

Of course with HTML 5 you also have to deal with the multiple-specs problem. The W3C publishes snapshots that you could use, and they are stable, but the [WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) is "living" so will keep changing.

Validator.nu is open source so you could [use their schema](https://github.com/validator/validator/tree/master/schema/html5), but it follows the living spec and is both subject to change and frequently out of date.

And that only deals with standards. If you want to deal with what browsers actually support (given they sometimes introduce non-standard features and usually don't have a full implementation of any given spec) then you're mostly out of luck. You might have some success in reading the data from sites such as [HTML 5 test](https://html5test.com/) and [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/) though.

And if you want to deal with things browsers don't support (i.e. what attributes they allow you to add to the DOM but will then ignore for anything that isn't code you wrote looking for them) then, as far as I know, everything is "accepted".

Comment: Thank you! Your answer certainly cleared a few other things for me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation of html attributes is browser-specific. One could implement a browser where `<div>` would accept `foo` as attribute. So if you try to test, whether `<div>` "accepts" `foo` as attribute, the result would depend on the browser.

Briefly: You can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the element type has the attribute as a *property* with the `in` operator.

```
var name = 'src';
var type = 'script';

if (name in document.createElement(type)) {
  console.log(type, 'has the attribute \'' + name + '\'');
} else {
  console.log(type, 'does not have the attribute \'' + name + '\'');
}
```

Note that, this tests if the object, an HTML element in this case has the property defined, not if its a valid HTML attribute for the element the object might represent, any property defined on the object will return true.

This means it has a couple of caveats, for example the `class` *attribute* is does not have a 1:1 mapping but is instead available via two properties, `classList` and `className`.

Comment: (a) Not all attributes map onto a property of the same name, (b) not all properties map onto an attribute of the same name (hello [false positive](http://jsbin.com/vojofam/1/edit?js,console)), (c) the question is asking if an element *can have* a given attribute, not if it *already* has it

Comment: `innerHTML` is hardly a false positive. `in` still returns true even if the value is undefined.

Comment: It is a false positive because `innerHTML` **is not an HTML attribute**, it is a DOM property that maps on to a serialisation of the element's child nodes.

Comment: Its a property yeah and its an approximation, but should be fine to "detect if `<li>` can have an `input` attribute set to it with `element.setAttribute`

Comment: It really isn't. [Here is a false negative](http://jsbin.com/vojofam/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: `className` obviously ;)